# Unrar to a certain folder and then delete source folder

Tags: rar

The following command works for `unrar` to extract an archive to a certain folder.

```
unrar e -r -o- /home/username/source/directory/*.rar /home/username/copy/extracted/to
```

Inside `/home/username/source/directory` there are some subdirectories with `.rar` archives and some other files (`.r01`, `.r02`, ...). I want to extract the `.rar` files to `/home/username/copy/extracted/to` and delete the `/home/username/source/directory` folder or all the files in that one folder.

In the above command, where should I put the delete command when the extracting is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

After OP's clarification that the .rar files are inside subdirectories, I think that this is a better approach.

Use `find` to find all .rar files in a directory and its subdirectories. Use `find`'s `-exec` flag to execute the `unrar` command to unrar the files and add `&& rm -r /home/username/source/directory` at the end to delete the `/home/username/source/directory` folder and its contents:

```bash
find /home/username/source/directory/ -type f -name "*.rar" -exec unrar e -o- {} /home/username/copy/extracted/to \; && rm -r /home/username/source/directory
```

---

**Old answer**

You can do the following:

```bash
for file in /home/username/source/directory/*.rar; do unrar e -r -o- "$file" /home/username/copy/extracted/to && rm -- "$file"; done
```